# Arduino project - will this fit together?

Tags: project

I'm about to order parts for my project and I'd like to avoid some rookie mistake I might've missed. I'll be using Arduino chip and a wifi module to host a very simple webpage and a battery to make this all portable. I've decided to use Arduino Mini Pro 8MHz because of 3.3V input voltage, same as ESP8266, also FT232RL to program the board and TPS73601 for my battery. This is where I have some doubts, the battery I've picked is Li-Ion from my old Samsung Galaxy S AFAIK when charged it supplies ~4.2V and nearly discharged ~2.7V so the regulator should work (?). Is using Li-Ion in any way different from regular AA or just +/- because I see 3 pins on the back of it? Except for charging of course I'll be using the phone for that. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: have you considered programming the esp8266 directly? It has a few GPIO pins and can host small webpages.

Comment: http://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server/

Comment: I had not known that, but I'll be using a couple of analog sensors in my project, did not include them here because they are pretty straight forward. I assume GPIO on ESP8266 are digital? If so then I'll have to stick with Arduino chip anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've provided everything seems to be compatible.

Concerning the battery, a quick look at the Arduino website shows:

> Input Voltage 3.35 -12 V (3.3V model)

Meaning the regulator will work as long as the battery provides voltage above 3.35 but since your battery's voltage drops as it gets depleted you might not get the battery life you'd expect :/. In other words: it'll work initially  until the voltage drops below 3.35V and then you would have to recharge it.

> Is using Li-Ion in any way different from regular AA

Yes and No.
No : both provide a stable DC source and both can be used in similar applications.

Yes: Li-Ion batteries can be recharged and have a longer life-span, and most importantly, Li-Ion batteries don't have a sharp voltage drop as they get depleted, unlike regular AA batteries. Which is a bonus for this project ( i guess :p )

> I see 3 pins on the back of it

There are only 2 pins that actually provide the power from the battery while the third is usually used to monitor temperature or battery life remaining.So you can use this battery by only connecting the power providing pins (usually indicated by + and - ) and safely ignore the third.

Gd Luck!